# Current state of characters in Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

I watched Dragon Ball, DBZ, DBGT, DB Super, but the order is such that DBGT is in the end I believe.

What happened to all the characters? On dragon Ball wikia, it said Goku died and is dead right now at Age 801, but I never saw this?

Comment: Where did you read that db end's with DBGT ?

Comment: GT takes place after Dragon Ball Z, but it's now non-canon; Dragon Ball Super replaced it, and it's still ongoing so there's no definitive end at this point.

Comment: GT was at best developed with Toriyama helping them, but he was not the main source of the story and characters. He was not in any real control, and therefor clasically the story is non canon, or a Spinoff. Because it was not him, it has Numerous plot holes and low quality story elements, which enforces the Non-canon aspects. DB super is however involved directly with him, and he is dictated a lot of the story, hence its Canon. It is also incompatible with GT, as the God modes are non existant in GT, especially vegeta's.

Answer (score 2):

Dragon Ball GT is non-canon, when you say Goku died is because he turn the guardian of the Dragon Balls (you can watch`Dragon Ball GT: A Hero's Legacy` to see that is true), but it doesn't matter because is not official, the official series is Dragon Ball Super.

Answer (score 0):

As has been rightly pointed out in the comments by [Torisuda](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/7579/torisuda) and [Ryan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/20610/ryan), Dragon Ball GT (DBGT) is non-canon, in fact, it never was canon.... 

So calling DBGT the end of the DB Series is outright wrong....

Also, DBGT has been replaced by Dragon Ball Super (DBS) and since DBS is ongoing, there is no definitive end to the series yet....

One must also keep in mind that the [Dragon Ball Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com) is based in a time where the series has continued on to another point altogether, owing to games like [Dragon Ball Xenoverse](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Xenoverse), [Dragon Ball Xenoverse 2](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Xenoverse_2), [Dragon Ball Heroes](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Heroes) etc... 

In this period (many many years down the line), Goku is long since gone....

---

Now to answer your question why you haven't seen the death is because

- DBGT ended in Age 790's, before Goku's death; He just left Earth riding on Shenron.
- [DBGT: A Hero's Legacy](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_GT:_A_Hero%27s_Legacy) (also non-canon) takes place almost 100 years after the Shadow Dragon Saga ends, by the time only Pan is alive... 
  Thus it only references the fact that Goku is dead and has no use showing how he died...
- DBS is ongoing and since it's ongoing, one can't say where it's going to end... It might end with Goku's death, it might not... It's anyone's guess...
- Also, it's not given in the [wikia page](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Goku) when he died after he was revived by Elder Kai. Using the above facts we can extrapolate that he died within the 100 years gap between DBGT and DBGT: A Hero's Legacy... Not to forget that neither is the reason for his death during this period mentioned, leaving it upto Akira Toriyama to bend the story according to his will....